# JqGrid, mostra sucesso no carregamento, mas não monta a Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

Estou com uma `grid` em meu site que uso o `JqGrid`. O que esta acontecendo é que quando os dados voltam da requisição, eles estão formatados da maneira correta porque o próprio `JqGrid` entra no método `loadComplete`, porém, ele não carrega esses dados na Grid.

Javascript do JqGrid.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        url: 'adm/controller/medico.php?acao=listarMedico',
        mtype: "POST",
        styleUI : 'Bootstrap',
        datatype: "json",
        colModel: [
            { label: 'id', name: 'idMedico', key: true, width: 75, hidden:true },
            { label: 'Nome', name: 'nomeMedico', width: 75 },
            { label: 'CRM', name: 'crmMedico', width: 150 },
            { label: 'Especialidades', name: 'especialidadesMedico', width: 150 },
            { label: 'Endereço', name: 'enderecoMedico', width: 150 },
            { label: 'Telefone', name: 'telefoneMedico', width: 150 }
        ],
        viewrecords: true,
        rowNum: 20,
        rowList: [20, 40, 100],
        //height: "auto",
        height: 400,
        emptyrecords: "Nenhum médico com o filtro selecionado",
        loadtext: "Buscando e carregando...",
        rowNum: 20,
        pager: "#jqGridPager",
        caption: "Médicos Conveniados",
        loadComplete: function(data){
            console.log('sucesso');
            console.log(data);
        },
        loadError: function (xhr,st,err) {
            console.log('HTTP status code: ' + xhr.status + '\n' +
                  'textStatus: ' + st + '\n' +
                  'errorThrown: ' + err);
            console.log('HTTP message body (jqXHR.responseText): ' + '\n' + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

O retorno que o PHP me traz e esse em JSON:

```
{
  "total": 1,
  "page": 1,
  "records": 20,
  "rows": {
    "1": {
      "id": "1",
      "cell": {
        "idMedico": "1",
        "nomeMedico": "dsda",
        "crmMedico": "jknjk",
        "especialidadesMedico": null,
        "enderecoMedico": " ,  -  - ",
        "telefoneMedico": "() "
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "id": "2",
      "cell": {
        "idMedico": "2",
        "nomeMedico": "Henrique",
        "crmMedico": "CRM",
        "especialidadesMedico": null,
        "enderecoMedico": " ,  -  - ",
        "telefoneMedico": "() "
      }
    },
    "3": {
      "id": "3",
      "cell": {
        "idMedico": "3",
        "nomeMedico": "Henrique",
        "crmMedico": "CRM",
        "especialidadesMedico": null,
        "enderecoMedico": " ,  -  - ",
        "telefoneMedico": "() "
      }
    },
    "4": {
      "id": "4",
      "cell": {
        "idMedico": "4",
        "nomeMedico": "Henrique",
        "crmMedico": "CRM",
        "especialidadesMedico": null,
        "enderecoMedico": " ,  -  - ",
        "telefoneMedico": "() "
      }
    },
    "5": {
      "id": "5",
      "cell": {
        "idMedico": "5",
        "nomeMedico": "Henrique",
        "crmMedico": "CRM",
        "especialidadesMedico": null,
        "enderecoMedico": "Endere\u00e7o , Bairro - \u00c1gua Doce do Norte  - ES",
        "telefoneMedico": "() "
      }
    },
    "6": {
      "id": "5",
      "cell": {
        "idMedico": "5",
        "nomeMedico": "Henrique",
        "crmMedico": "CRM",
        "especialidadesMedico": null,
        "enderecoMedico": "Endere\u00e7o , Bairro - \u00c1gua Doce do Norte  - ES",
        "telefoneMedico": "() "
      }
    },
    "7": {
      "id": "5",
      "cell": {
        "idMedico": "5",
        "nomeMedico": "Henrique",
        "crmMedico": "CRM",
        "especialidadesMedico": null,
        "enderecoMedico": "Endereco , Bairro - Afonso Cl\u00e1udio - ES",
        "telefoneMedico": "() "
      }
    },
    "8": {
      "id": "5",
      "cell": {
        "idMedico": "5",
        "nomeMedico": "Henrique",
        "crmMedico": "CRM",
        "especialidadesMedico": null,
        "enderecoMedico": "Endereco , Bairro - Afonso Cl\u00e1udio - ES",
        "telefoneMedico": "() "
      }
    },
    "9": {
      "id": "6",
      "cell": {
        "idMedico": "6",
        "nomeMedico": "Henrique",
        "crmMedico": "CRM",
        "especialidadesMedico": null,
        "enderecoMedico": " ,  -  - ",
        "telefoneMedico": "() "
      }
    },
    "10": {
      "id": "7",
      "cell": {
        "idMedico": "7",
        "nomeMedico": "Henrique",
        "crmMedico": "CRM",
        "especialidadesMedico": null,
        "enderecoMedico": " ,  -  - ",
        "telefoneMedico": "() "
      }
    },
    "11": {
      "id": "8",
      "cell": {
        "idMedico": "8",
        "nomeMedico": "Henrique",
        "crmMedico": "CRM",
        "especialidadesMedico": null,
        "enderecoMedico": "Endere\u00e7o , Bairro - Afonso Cl\u00e1udio - ES",
        "telefoneMedico": "() "
      }
    },
    "12": {
      "id": "8",
      "cell": {
        "idMedico": "8",
        "nomeMedico": "Henrique",
        "crmMedico": "CRM",
        "especialidadesMedico": null,
        "enderecoMedico": "Endere\u00e7o , Bairro - Afonso Cl\u00e1udio - ES",
        "telefoneMedico": "() "
      }
    },
    "13": {
      "id": "9",
      "cell": {
        "idMedico": "9",
        "nomeMedico": "Henrique",
        "crmMedico": "CRM",
        "especialidadesMedico": null,
        "enderecoMedico": "Endere\u00e7o , Bairro - Afonso Cl\u00e1udio - ES",
        "telefoneMedico": "() "
      }
    },
    "14": {
      "id": "9",
      "cell": {
        "idMedico": "9",
        "nomeMedico": "Henrique",
        "crmMedico": "CRM",
        "especialidadesMedico": null,
        "enderecoMedico": "Endereco , Bairro - \u00c1gua Doce do Norte - ES",
        "telefoneMedico": "() "
      }
    },
    "15": {
      "id": "10",
      "cell": {
        "idMedico": "10",
        "nomeMedico": "Henrique",
        "crmMedico": "CRM",
        "especialidadesMedico": null,
        "enderecoMedico": "Endere\u00e7o , Bairro - Afonso Cl\u00e1udio - ES",
        "telefoneMedico": "(81) 98125-8886"
      }
    },
    "16": {
      "id": "10",
      "cell": {
        "idMedico": "10",
        "nomeMedico": "Henrique",
        "crmMedico": "CRM",
        "especialidadesMedico": null,
        "enderecoMedico": "Endereco , Bairro - \u00c1gua Doce do Norte - ES",
        "telefoneMedico": "() "
      }
    },
    "17": {
      "id": "11",
      "cell": {
        "idMedico": "11",
        "nomeMedico": "Henrique",
        "crmMedico": "CRM",
        "especialidadesMedico": null,
        "enderecoMedico": "Endere\u00e7o , Bairro - Afonso Cl\u00e1udio - ES",
        "telefoneMedico": "(81) 98200-5300"
      }
    },
    "18": {
      "id": "11",
      "cell": {
        "idMedico": "11",
        "nomeMedico": "Henrique",
        "crmMedico": "CRM",
        "especialidadesMedico": null,
        "enderecoMedico": "Endere\u00e7o , Bairro - Afonso Cl\u00e1udio - ES",
        "telefoneMedico": "(81) 98125-8886"
      }
    },
    "19": {
      "id": "11",
      "cell": {
        "idMedico": "11",
        "nomeMedico": "Henrique",
        "crmMedico": "CRM",
        "especialidadesMedico": null,
        "enderecoMedico": "Endereco , Bairro - \u00c1gua Doce do Norte - ES",
        "telefoneMedico": "() "
      }
    },
    "20": {
      "id": "12",
      "cell": {
        "idMedico": "12",
        "nomeMedico": "Henrique",
        "crmMedico": "CRM",
        "especialidadesMedico": null,
        "enderecoMedico": "Endere\u00e7o , Bairro - Afonso Cl\u00e1udio - ES",
        "telefoneMedico": "(81) 98200-5300"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alguém saberia o porque o JqGrid não esta montando os dados na Grid?

Answer (score 1):

O problema foi resolvido.
Fiz essa mesma pergunta no [stackoverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34934752/jqgrid-shows-success-in-load-but-does-not-mount-the-grid/34935719#34935719), e a resposta que me deram me ajudou a resolver o problema.
No meu JSON eu não montei o rows da maneira que o JqGrid espera que é na chave do rows ser dessa maneira:

```
[
    {"idMedico":"1",...},
    {"idMedico":"2",...},
    ...
    {"idMedico":"12",...}
]
```

Para conseguir isso, no PHP eu criei a chave `rows` no `array` X, montei um `array`separado com as linhas que queria e dei um `array_push` passando o `array` X e especificando a chave `rows`.